# a question about clearcase: how to open a file checked out in emacs?

Tags: command, clearcase

I have a question about clearcase. in linux, I open a terminal, and use "xclearcase" command to lunch file browser of clearcase. Then I check out a file and I want to open it in Emacs, I know I should cd to the folder contains the checked out file, but before I do this, the terminal still effected by the "xclearcase" command, how could I type some commands now?

Comment: You can also check out the file without ever leaving Emacs using [vc-clearcase mode](http://code.google.com/p/vc-clearcase/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch `xclearcase`, do so by adding a `&` to the end of it. This will make the shell send it to the background so you can do more stuff in your shell. E.g.

```
xclearcase &
```

That will allow you to further interact with your shell while xclearcase is running.

Also, if you're working in the terminal, I would recommend getting comfortable with `cleartool` for basic operations. For example, to checkout and edit a file:

```
cleartool co src/path/to/file.c
emacs src/path/to/file.c
```

Then, to checkin the file:

```
cleartool ci src/path/to/file.c
```

Comment: thank you, it helps, I try to ctrl+z and then type "bg", it also works?

Answer (score 0):

As [Nemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768469/nemo) mentions in the comments, the [vc-clearcase](http://code.google.com/p/vc-clearcase/) Emacs mode allows you to checkout a file right from an Emacs session (<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>).

- It will handle hijacked file,  asking whether to keep the changes in said hijacked file through the question "Claim lock retaining changes?"
- It will ask for a comment
- It allows for checkouting a directory
- It handle file with a `-nocheckout` rule on their config spec